# MSVC localtime vs localtime_s

Tags: datetime, visual-c++

I'm using MSVS 2008, and have a problem with time conversions.

This works fine:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
strftime (LBUF, 256, "Timestamp = %A, %d/%m/%Y %T\0", timeinfo);
```

but this one crashes:

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
localtime_s (&timeinfo, &rawtime);
strftime (LBUF, 256, "Timestamp = %A, %d/%m/%Y %T\0", &timeinfo);
```

The crash occurs on the *strftime* call, but why?

Comment: What is `LBUF`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Sorry,  LBUF is char [256]

Comment: Found the problem. My first example did not in fact include the %T format specifier. The second one did, and replacing it with %H:%M:%S (which %T  is supposed to be equivalent to) fixed the problem. Crashing does seem to be a rather severe consequence, though!

Comment: Well the `"%T"` specifier is not mentioned in the [Windows documentation of `strftime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l), probably leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Mea culpa ... apologies!